# How to invoke auto-completer doc function in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm looking for it for few hours by now and I cannot find any way to easily create comments like the example(in PhpStorm):

```
/**
* @param param1 
* @return boolean
*/
function myFunc(param1) {…}
```

Comment: CMD+N → PHPDoc Blocks... is a quick way. Not sure what the CMD key equivalent on Windows is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type a function in your IDE, place a cursor before it:

```
|
function myFunc($param1) {
  return 'foo';
}
```

Then type: `/**` and press enter:

```
/**[ENTER]
function myFunc($param1) {
  return 'foo';
}
```

It will generate PHPDoc automatically.